# Set directory path from resource folder errors in jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, io, freemarker

I am trying to set templates path for FreeMarker templates. I am storing the template files inside a directory in resources and use ResourceUtils to set the path.
`freemarkerConfig.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:templates"));`

This runs perfectly fine when I deploy the application locally. But, when application jar is deployed in a docker container, it fails as it is not able to find the path `jar:file:/app.jar!/templates`. I know I should be using InputStream from a ClassPathReosurce, when accessing files from a jar. But how to set a directory location from a jar?

Comment: May be you could try setClassForTemplateLoading(java.lang.Class resourceLoaderClass, java.lang.String basePackagePath)?

Comment: Thanks @alexq for the comment. Can you please explain in detail how to configure the resourceLoaderClass?

Comment: Try getClass() as resourceLoaderClass and "/templates" as basePackagePath.

Comment: Thanks @alexq, this works.